# SQL selecting row specific data by type

Tags: sql-server

After numerous joins building a query, I stuck in a table of products with 3 column identifies ID-Color-Size and the column of data barcode like

| Id | Color | Size | Barcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 40 | 4 | 5205barcode1 |
| 34 | 40 | 4 | extradata1 |
| 34 | 40 | 5 | 5205barcode2 |
| 34 | 40 | 5 | extradata2 |
| 34 | 41 | 4 | 5205barcode3 |
| 34 | 41 | 4 | extradata3 |
| 35 | 40 | 5 | 5205barcode4 |
| 35 | 40 | 5 | extradata4 |
| 34 | 40 | 3 | data4 |
| 35 | 39 | 5 | data5 |
| 35 | 40 | 3 | data6 |

I need to keep the unique combinations of ID-Color-Size with *barcode* (starting with '5205%') and remove the rows with same id-color-size (the extradata1-5 are considered duplicate).

The final table would have unique combinations of ID-Color-Size-barcode1-4 and *data4-5-6*

Comment: It's not clear what you want with the barcode. You need to keep just the 'barcode1' part? Or the 5205 part?

Comment: the "5205barcode1" is considered a barcode. I need to keep all of them as primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need a window function to order duplicates of id/color/size by the barcode and only select those where the barcode starts 5205:

```
with p as (
select *,
    Row_Number() over(partition by id, color, size order by case when barcode like '5205%' then 1 end desc) rn
from t
)
select id, color, size, barcode
from p
where rn=1
```

Comment: thank you @stu it was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Ofc I have vote you. Sorry I am still missing some reputation to make my votes count.